# iOS Second Screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the PhoneGap ExternalScreen plugin, but I have modified it slightly to be able to support multiple resolutions. I got some tips from Matt Gemmel's post on iPadVGAOutput (http://mattgemmell.com/2010/06/01/ipad-vga-output/) Here is what my code looks like:

```
- (void) toggleResolution:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
{
    self.callbackID = [arguments pop];
    if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1){
        externalScreen = [[[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1] retain];
        screenModes = [externalScreen.availableModes retain];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"External Display Size"
                                                    message:@"Choose a size for the external display."
                                                    delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];

        for (UIScreenMode *mode in screenModes){
            CGSize modeScreenSize = mode.size;
            [alert addButtonWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f x %.0f pixels", modeScreenSize.width, modeScreenSize.height]];
        }
        [alert show];
    } else {
        PluginResult* pluginResult = [PluginResult resultWithStatus:PGCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:WEBVIEW_UNAVAILABLE];
        [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toErrorCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
    }    
}



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIScreenMode *desiredMode = [screenModes objectAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    externalScreen.currentMode = desiredMode;
    externalWindow.screen = externalScreen;    
    [screenModes release];

    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
    rect.size = desiredMode.size;
    externalWindow.frame = rect;
    externalWindow.clipsToBounds = YES;

    externalWindow.hidden = NO;
    [externalWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

    PluginResult* pluginResult = [PluginResult resultWithStatus:PGCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:WEBVIEW_OK];
    [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
}
```

The resolution is changing just fine, but the content is not being constrained inside of the correct dimensions. An example is as follows:

When the second screen is originally loaded (at 1920x1080), it looks like this: http://cl.ly/F5IV

After changing the resolution to 1280x720, it looks like this: http://cl.ly/F41K

I am relatively new to Objective-C, but am quickly picking it up. Any pointers on solving my problem and/or improving the code altogether would be great. Thanks!

Andrew

***EDIT**: I also wanted to clarify, I am not manually setting any width/height on any of the views and/or CSS that is being displayed.*

Comment: Are you forced to use a secondary screen? Can you get away with iOS mirroring? I've found that mirroring provides a much better overall experience compared to 2nd screen. It may not meet your requirements, but it's worth evaluating.

Comment: Alan, Unfortunately we are forced to use a second screen because the second screen has a 16:9 ratio and the iPad is a 4:3. We will basically be mirroring, but unless you know a way to get rid of the black bars without writing the second screen code manually, we are stuck! :(

Comment: Ahh ipad...crap. It works pretty well with an iPhone4 in landscape. I just checked our ipad app on a 30" Display, and it has black bars.

Comment: Why are black bars out of the question? Works for movies presented in their correct aspect ratio. Just curious. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one found it, I started to dig into the Objective-C and solved it. I had to add the following to the `alertView` method:

```
webView.frame = rect;
```

Answer (score 1):

As your solution didn't work for me I'll put my solution to this here. I was getting the black bars around the view too although the screens dimension was detected right. I just had to set

```
[externScreen  setOverscanCompensation: UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetApplicationFrame];
```

and the bars were gone.